# How can Fn keys be captured in iOS

Tags: ios

I'm trying to capture Fn keys hit while a UIWebView is in focus so that I can send them to a web app. The iOS emulator seems to assume that I am sending system commands, but I want to send Fn keys to the app. In the documentation, I believe it says that Ctrl+Fn key will send the Fn key, but this doesn't work.
  Using the iPad and a Bluetooth keyboard, it doesn't seem to respond to these keys either. I tried capturing the F2 key, for example, by overriding UIApplication's keyCommands property like this:

```
unichar c = 0xf705;
NSString *tokens  = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&c length:1];
```

And adding that token to an array of key modifiers, but nothing comes through. That technique of using the 8-bit encoding works fine with other characters such as 'a', but no dice on F2. Any ideas?